# Keep ConfigParser output files sorted

Tags: python, configuration, configparser

I've noticed with my source control that the content of the output files generated with ConfigParser is never in the same order. Sometimes sections will change place or options inside sections even without any modifications to the values.

Is there a way to keep things sorted in the configuration file so that I don't have to commit trivial changes every time I launch my application?

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1984759/export-with-alphabetical-sort-in-python-configparser/1984787#1984787) to a similar question gives some suggestions on how to accomplish sorted output in Python 2.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Looks like this was fixed in [Python 3.1](http://docs.python.org/dev/py3k/whatsnew/3.1.html) and 2.7 with the introduction of ordered dictionaries:

> The standard library now supports use
>   of ordered dictionaries in several
>   modules. The configparser module uses
>   them by default. This lets
>   configuration files be read, modified,
>   and then written back in their
>   original order.

Comment: In Python 2.7, you can `from collections import OrderedDict` and use `ConfigParser(dict_type=OrderedDict)` to make the parser use an ordered dictionary. Based on a minimal amount of testing, I think this should serve you well.

Comment: In Python 2.7 you do not need to do that eksortso, it is the default.

Answer (score 5):

If you want to take it a step further than Alexander Ljungberg's answer and also sort the sections and the contents of the sections you can use the following:

```
config = ConfigParser.ConfigParser({}, collections.OrderedDict)
config.read('testfile.ini')
# Order the content of each section alphabetically
for section in config._sections:
    config._sections[section] = collections.OrderedDict(sorted(config._sections[section].items(), key=lambda t: t[0]))

# Order all sections alphabetically
config._sections = collections.OrderedDict(sorted(config._sections.items(), key=lambda t: t[0] ))

# Write ini file to standard output
config.write(sys.stdout)
```

This uses OrderdDict dictionaries (to keep ordering) and sorts the read ini file from outside ConfigParser by overwriting the internal _sections dictionary.

Answer (score 2):

No. The ConfigParser library writes things out in dictionary hash order.  (You can see this if you look at the source code.)  There are replacements for this module that do a better job.

I will see if I can find one and add it here.

http://www.voidspace.org.uk/python/configobj.html#introduction is the one I was thinking of.  It's not a drop-in replacement, but it is very easy to use.

Answer (score -1):

ConfigParser is based on the ini file format, who in it's design is supposed to NOT be sensitive to order. If your config file format is sensitive to order, you can't use ConfigParser. It may also confuse people if you have an ini-type format that is sensitive to the order of the statements...

Comment: It is still helpful to have the items come out in the same order if you are versioning the results and want to see reasonable-looking diffs from version to version.

Comment: Ah, right. I completely missed that you were creating files. My bad. It's configPARSER after all. ;)