# How to sort OrderedDict of OrderedDict?

Tags: python, sorting, nested, ordereddictionary

I'm trying to sort OrderedDict in OrderedDict by **'depth'** key.
Is there any solution to sort that Dictionary ?

```
OrderedDict([
  (2, OrderedDict([
    ('depth', 0),  
    ('height', 51), 
    ('width', 51),   
    ('id', 100)
  ])), 
  (1, OrderedDict([
    ('depth', 2),  
    ('height', 51), 
    ('width', 51),  
    ('id', 55)
  ])), 
  (0, OrderedDict([
    ('depth', 1),  
    ('height', 51), 
    ('width', 51),  
    ('id', 48)
  ])),
])
```

Sorted dict should look like this:

```
OrderedDict([
  (2, OrderedDict([
    ('depth', 0),  
    ('height', 51), 
    ('width', 51),   
    ('id', 100)
  ])), 
  (0, OrderedDict([
    ('depth', 1),  
    ('height', 51), 
    ('width', 51),  
    ('id', 48)
  ])),
  (1, OrderedDict([
    ('depth', 2),  
    ('height', 51), 
    ('width', 51),  
    ('id', 55)
  ])), 
])
```

Any idea how to get it?

Answer (score 119, accepted):

You'll have to create a new one since `OrderedDict` is sorted by insertion order.

In your case the code would look like this:

```
foo = OrderedDict(sorted(foo.items(), key=lambda x: x[1]['depth']))
```

See http://docs.python.org/dev/library/collections.html#ordereddict-examples-and-recipes for more examples.

Note for Python 2 you will need to use `.iteritems()` instead of `.items()`.

Comment: This will cause an exception if any dict doesn't have 'depth' as a key.  This might be desired.  If it isn't, you can assume a default key by using "get".

Comment: Note that `[1]` here refers to foo's values, as opposed to its keys, which would be `[0]`

Answer (score 21):

```
>>> OrderedDict(sorted(od.items(), key=lambda item: item[1]['depth']))
```

Answer (score 5):

Sometimes you might want to keep the initial dictionary and not create a new one.

In that case you could do the following:

```
temp = sorted(list(foo.items()), key=lambda x: x[1]['depth'])
foo.clear()
foo.update(temp)
```

Comment: I am curious, can you give an example when one would want to clear and update an existing dictionary, instead of re-assigning it?

Comment: When you are handling dicts that might have been subclassed

Comment: @johnson Good point. A real world example for those not convinced:

I recently ran across a situation using ruamel.yaml, where if I wanted to rearrange a `CommentedMap` type using custom sorting, this is could be appropriate, or else it wouldn't be able to serialize. Not sure if the `CommentedMap` constructor would have been able to be used for this.