# In an OrderedDict how to sort by a particular attribute?

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, ordereddictionary

I am trying to sort the following OrderedDict by doing the following-->

```
>>> from collections import OrderedDict
>>> d = OrderedDict([(4995L, [{'isbn_13': u'9788131805923', 'book_quantity': 49L, 'seller_book_id': 4995L, 'book_id': 4995L, 'title': u'Industrial Automation and Robotics', 'selling_price': 292.0, 'id': 4995L, 'condition': 'New Book'}]), (6657L, [{'isbn_13': u'9788122425925', 'book_quantity': 49L, 'seller_book_id': 6657L, 'book_id': 6657L, 'title': u'A Textbook of Agricultural Statistics', 'selling_price': 243.0, 'id': 6657L, 'condition': 'New Book'}]), (6137L, [{'isbn_13': u'9788122425727\n', 'book_quantity': 50L, 'seller_book_id': 6137L, 'book_id': 6137L, 'title': u'A Guide to Corporate Governance', 'selling_price': 247.0, 'id': 6137L, 'condition': 'New Book'}]), (6260L, [{'isbn_13': u'9788122414394\n', 'book_quantity': 50L, 'seller_book_id': 6260L, 'book_id': 6260L, 'title': u'Management Accounting \n', 'selling_price': 269.0, 'id': 6260L, 'condition': 'New Book'}])])


>>> OrderedDict(sorted(d.items(), key=lambda item: item[1][0]['selling_price']))
```

by the `selling_price` attribute. But I am not being able to do it.

I tried to apply the concept discussed in this [How to sort OrderedDict of OrderedDict?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8031418/how-to-sort-ordereddict-in-ordereddict-python) for normal OrderedDict but it did not work. Can someone please help me out? TIA

Answer (score 10, accepted):

### Solution

This should work for the ordered dictionary `d`:

```
OrderedDict(sorted(d.items(), key=lambda item: item[1][0]['selling_price']))
```

### Application

```
>>> d
OrderedDict([(7484,
              [{'book_id': 7484,
                'book_quantity': 43,
                'condition': 'New Book',
                'id': 7484,
                'isbn_13': '9788131727591',
                'seller_book_id': 7484,
                'selling_price': 629.0,
                'title': 'Network Management:  Principles and Practice,  2/e'}]),
             (7485,
              [{'book_id': 7484,
                'book_quantity': 43,
                'condition': 'New Book',
                'id': 7484,
                'isbn_13': '9788131727591',
                'seller_book_id': 7484,
                'selling_price': 29.0,
                'title': 'Network Management:  Principles and Practice,  2/e'}])])

>>> OrderedDict(sorted(d.items(), key=lambda item: item[1][0]['selling_price']))
OrderedDict([(7485,
              [{'book_id': 7484,
                'book_quantity': 43,
                'condition': 'New Book',
                'id': 7484,
                'isbn_13': '9788131727591',
                'seller_book_id': 7484,
                'selling_price': 29.0,
                'title': 'Network Management:  Principles and Practice,  2/e'}]),
             (7484,
              [{'book_id': 7484,
                'book_quantity': 43,
                'condition': 'New Book',
                'id': 7484,
                'isbn_13': '9788131727591',
                'seller_book_id': 7484,
                'selling_price': 629.0,
                'title': 'Network Management:  Principles and Practice,  2/e'}])])
```

Sorted by `'selling_price': 29.0` is less than `'selling_price': 629.0`.

Comment: For clarity, unpacking the tuple in the lambda might be clearer :) `lambda (k, v): v[0]['selling_price'])` for example

Comment: @MikeMüller I tried doing this 

`data = OrderedDict((k, v) for k, v in sorted(data.items(),key=lambda item: item[1][0]['selling_price']))` 

but it did not work

Comment: @Subhajit Updated my answer.

Comment: @Wolph Your suggestion works with Python 2 but not with Python 3.

Comment: I tried this too --> `data = OrderedDict(sorted(data.items(), key=lambda item: item[1][0]['selling_price']))` still it is not sorted!

Comment: @Wolph I am using 2 but it is still not working

Comment: @Subhajit Sorts my example. See update.

Comment: @MikeMüller: true, forgot about that

Comment: I am not sure where I am messing it up! It still does not work for me @MikeMüller

Comment: @Subhajit Did you figure it out?

Comment: @MikeMüller Yes, I kind of did ! and that led to to this problem ->
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34240104/how-to-get-n-search-objects-from-a-searchqueryset-without-changing-the-type

Comment: @Subhajit Looks like this answer solved this question. You can [accept](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) an answer if it solves your problem. Let's work on the new problem in the new question.

Comment: @MikeMüller, I am sorry I almost forgot!

Comment: In python3 it is `iteritems()` rather than python2's `items()`

Comment: The other way around. Try it out with a dictionary.

Comment: Yep sorry - you are quite correct