# How to get n search objects from a SearchQuerySet without changing the type?

Tags: python, django, elasticsearch, django-haystack, searchqueryset

I am trying to get the to 10 objects like :

```
q_auth = SearchQuerySet().filter(content=validate_query)
q_auth = q_auth[:10]
print type(q_auth)
```

The output I want is: `<class 'haystack.query.SearchQuerySet'>` but I am getting is `<type 'list'>`.

Can some one please help me out?

Comment: Why would you expect the type to be a `SearchQuerySet`? It's a list afterall

Comment: @RohitJain uhm.. I can see where the OP is coming from: [the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/db/queries/#limiting-querysets) say it's still a queryset

Comment: @Pynchia Hmm, I see.

Comment: Apparently nobody can reproduce the situation. Can you please provide more context to the problem?

Comment: @RohitJain I want <class 'haystack.query.SearchQuerySet'> as the output.

Comment: @Pynchia did you try doing `[5:10]` or something similar operation on the search object?

Comment: Add `print q_auth` to see what you actually get.

Comment: @Pynchia I am printing these -> `print type(books[:10])     print books       print type(books)` and I am getting the following output ->http://dpaste.com/30RVPV8

Answer (score 1):

I tried something similar like your code but got the output like this:

```
<class 'django.db.models.query.QuerySet'>
```

Based on what you've got, I think you can try something like:

```
print type(q_auth[0])
```

Comment: Me too, I cannot reproduce the `<type 'list'>`

Comment: You can also iterate in, for me, a more Pythonic way: `_q_auth = iter(q_auth); next(_q_auth)`

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the [source](https://github.com/django-haystack/django-haystack/blob/master/haystack/query.py), you will see that `q_auth[:10]` returns a list of results. A `SearchQuerySet` is lazy and might not have all the results until you retrieve them with slicing, i.e. `q_auth[:10]`.

Just do:

```
first_results = q_auth[:10]
```

and access a result with:

```
first_results[0]
```

I recommend not to do this:

```
q_auth = q_auth[:10]
```

because your instance `q_auth` of `SearchQuerySet` would not be available for retrieving more results later.

Comment: It's converting the type. I want the type to be `<class 'haystack.query.SearchQuerySet'>` but it gives me  a list

Comment: `q_auth`  is of this type already. Slicing returns a list. That is how it is implemented. Actually, it makes a lot of sense. Please try the code in my answer.  Use a different name for your slicing result and `q_auth` keeps its type.

Comment: I tried the code in your answer, but it changed the type. So I changed my code to use a list rather than the search object.

Comment: Good to hear. If this answer contributed to the solution, consider accepting.

Comment: Sorry but this did not help much as it was changing the type , I had to rewrite my code for a list