# Define a sorted function for timestamps/time objects by key

Tags: python, python-2.7, sorteddictionary

I have a dictionary of times and counts. I need to sort the dict so that it is in ascending order by time. I need help getting the sort to do something useful. Right now I am dropping the AM/PM to remove complexity but I am aware that I'm running into a problem there since I'm losing information.

Calling

```
sorted(myDict, key = bytime_key)
```

with

```
def bytime_key(input):
    shorter_input = re.match(r'^(.*) \w\w$', input).group(1)
    time = datetime.strptime(shorter_input, '%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S')
    return(time)
```

is fine, save that it doesn't actually change the order, so I'm missing something fundamental here.

**Sample dictionary**

```
myDict = {'1/15/2016 10:41:00 AM': 11, '1/15/2016 10:43:00 AM': 4,
          '1/15/2016 10:22:00 AM': 46, '1/15/2016 10:30:00 AM': 15,
          '1/15/2016 10:59:00 AM': 34, '1/15/2016 12:06:00 PM': 12,
          '1/15/2016 11:42:00 AM': 11, '1/15/2016 12:22:00 PM': 1,
          '1/15/2016 12:18:00 PM': 5, '1/15/2016 10:52:00 AM': 6}
```

Comment: order of what? `dict` does not have any order, `sorted` returns a `list` and does not modify input in place. see [How to sort OrderedDict](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8031431/1176601) though

Answer (score 2):

[strptime](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior) allows for `%p` directive.

> `%p`  Locale’s equivalent of either AM or PM.  AM, PM (en_US); am, pm
>   (de_DE) (1), (2)

Key function may be simplified to:

```
from datetime import datetime

result = sorted(myDict, key=lambda s: datetime.strptime(s, "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S %p"))
expected = ['1/15/2016 10:22:00 AM', '1/15/2016 10:30:00 AM', 
            '1/15/2016 10:41:00 AM', '1/15/2016 10:43:00 AM',
            '1/15/2016 10:52:00 AM', '1/15/2016 10:59:00 AM', 
            '1/15/2016 11:42:00 AM', '1/15/2016 12:06:00 PM',
            '1/15/2016 12:18:00 PM', '1/15/2016 12:22:00 PM']
assert result == expected
```

Note that dictionaries are inherently unsorted structures. What you can do is perform sorting of keys / values / key-value pairs and create an ordered representation of data sorted in dictionary. And that's what your code does - it sorts keys.

Answer (score 1):

Standard Python dictionaries are unordered and will not preserve any ordering from a sort.

You could use the [OrderedDict](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict) to order the items in the dictionary based on their insertion times.

```
from collections import OrderedDict

ordered_times = OrderedDict(sorted(myDict.keys(), key=bytime_key))
```

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 problems that come to mind.  1st, dicts are not sortable.  You might want to use an `OrderedDict`.  Second, sorted doesn't sort the 1st argument, it returns a sorted copy of first argument.

Try changing the line in `bytime_key` from:

```
shorter_input = re.match(r'^(.*) \w\w$', input).group(1)
```

to

```
shorter_input = re.match(r'^(.*) \w\w$', input[0]).group(1)
```

Then get the OrderedDict using:

```
from collections import OrderedDict
my_sorted_dict = OrderedDict(sorted(myDict.iteritems(), key = bytime_key))
```

Answer (score 0):

[Sorted](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#sorted) returns a new list, so it won't modify your dictionary.  Consider using [list.sort()](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html) to sort in place.

[Dictionaries](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table) don't have an order associated with them.  They are very fast (O(1)) at looking up items, but aren't as useful for other operations.

Consider using a list of tuples (timestamp, count) or an [OrderedDictionary](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict).