# Why is 'key' function appended to the end of my OrderedDict when sorting?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am using python 3.6.5 and I am sorting an `OrderedDict`, e.g. `tmp.py`:

```
from collections import OrderedDict
d = OrderedDict()
d[6] = 'a'
d[5] = 'b'
d[3] = 'c'
d[4] = 'd'
print(d)
print("keys : {}".format(d.keys()))
d = OrderedDict(sorted(d.items()), key=lambda t: t[1])
print(d)
print("keys : {}".format(d.keys()))
```

When I run `tmp.py`, I get :

```
OrderedDict([(6, 'a'), (5, 'b'), (3, 'c'), (4, 'd')])
keys : odict_keys([6, 5, 3, 4])
OrderedDict([(3, 'c'), (4, 'd'), (5, 'b'), (6, 'a'), ('key', <function <lambda> at 0x2ab444506bf8>)])
keys : odict_keys([3, 4, 5, 6, 'key'])
```

Clearly the process of sorting has appended the `key()` function to my new `OrderedDict`.  I believe that I am sorting this in the same fashion prescribed in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8031431/4021436) post.

**QUESTION** : 
Why does this happen and how to I properly sort an `OrderedDict`?

Comment: Because you're passing `key=...` to `OrderedDict`, not to `sorted`.

Comment: This question has already been answered here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8031418/how-to-sort-ordereddict-of-ordereddict-python

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your brackets are in the wrong place.

```
d = OrderedDict(sorted(d.items()), key=lambda t: t[1])
```

should be:

```
d = OrderedDict(sorted(d.items(), key=lambda t: t[1]))
```

Comment: very good. I think you are right.