# Sorting a dictionary by value where value is a dictionary

Tags: python, sorting, dictionary

I am looking for a way to sort a dictionary by values. But here is the catch, my values are dictionaries as well. So I want to sort by my value dictionary's first value.

For example given the dictionary:

```
x = {'a':{'b':1, 'c':2, 'd':3}, 'e':{'f':3, 'g':4, 'h':5}, 'i':{'j':2, 'k':3, 'l':4}}
```

I would like the dictionary to be sorted by the values 'b', 'f', and 'j'. The sorted dictionary would return as:

```
x = {'a':{'b':1, 'c':2, 'd':3}, 'i':{'j':2, 'k':3, 'l':4}, 'e':{'f':3, 'g':4, 'h':5}}
```

Any help would be amazing. Preferably, I am looking for a solution that uses the sorted method along with lambdas.

Comment: When you say "first", do you mean "any arbitrary value"? Because the inner dictionaries are *also* not ordered by anything in particular, so you might not get `'b'` `'f'` and `'j'` as the three first keys if you built those inner dictionaries differently. If you want "the value corresponding to the first key in alphabetical order", that's a different thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Default `dict` type don't ordered.
Use [`collections.OrderedDict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#ordereddict-objects).
[Sort `OrderedDict` question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8031418/how-to-sort-ordereddict-of-ordereddict)

Comment: This helped a lot. Here was my final solution `sorted(monthcounts.items(), key=lambda x: x[1]['fieldname'], reverse=True)`. However, this assumes that all fields being compared share the same name.

Answer (score 0):

Dictionaries in Python are not explicitly ordered. ATM in an iterable they are guaranteed to return keys in the order they were inserted. Try using an `OrderedDict` dictionary from the `collections` package if you will be using dictionaries like this frequently. If you're only interested in sorting the dictionary based on its values first value, the following will work.

```
def get_sort_key(x):
    def get_key(elt):
        for k, v in x[elt].items():
            return v
    return get_key

sorted(x, key=get_sort_key(x))
```

This returns a list of the main dict's keys in order. The iterator of a dictionary is a list of the keys, so it's probably better to use sorted on `x.items()` and then construct a new dictionary from that.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `sorted` function and supply it a combination of `next` and `iter` as the key:

```
x = dict(sorted(x.items(), key=lambda y: next(iter(y))))
```

This works by turning the dict into an iterator and next gets the first key from that iterator, as sorted returns a list thus being a list of `key, value` tuples use dict on the sorted result to get a dict as a result.

```
{'a': {'b': 1, 'c': 2, 'd': 3}, 'e': {'f': 3, 'g': 4, 'h': 5}, 'i': {'j': 2, 'k': 3, 'l': 4}}
```

Comment: This isn't quite right, as it sorts by key, not by the corresponding value. The expected result according to the question is that the `2` from the `'j'` key ends up sorting its dictionary ahead of the `3` from the `'f'` key.