# How to change order of sections in INI files with Python?

Tags: python, ini

I want to sort the sections on an .ini file based on the numerical value in one of the keys of the sections.

I tried to use the OrderedDict method described here but it's not working for me, ([Define order of config.ini entries when writing to file with configparser?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49722215/define-order-of-config-ini-entries-when-writing-to-file-with-configparser)).

INI file:

```
[DATA] 
datalist = ALL, cc, ch

[DATA.dict]

[DATA.dict.ALL] 
type = Default 
from = 748.0 
to = 4000.0 
line = 0

[DATA.dict.cc] 
type = Energy 
from = 3213.9954023 
to = 3258.85057471 
line = 1

[DATA.dict.ch] 
type = Energy 
from = 1127.11016043 
to = 1210.58395722 
line = 2
```

goal is to sort the sections by the 'from' value and change the line value to match that, ie the 'h' section should be changed to line = 1 and moved up.

I have written code to make a list of the 'from' values and change the 'line' value based on that order. I have also got the code to put the 'datalist' in the correct order. I just don't know how to actually get the sections to change to that order as well.

Right now my output file looks like:

```
[DATA]
datalist = ALL, h, cc

[DATA.dict]

[DATA.dict.ALL]
type = Default
from = 748.0
to = 4000.0
line = 0

[DATA.dict.cc]
type = Energy
from = 3213.9954023
to = 3258.85057471
line = 2

[DATA.dict.h]
type = Energy
from = 1127.11016043
to = 1210.58395722
line = 1
```

What I want it to look like is this:

```
[DATA]
datalist = ALL, h, cc

[DATA.dict]

[DATA.dict.ALL]
type = Default
from = 748.0
to = 4000.0
line = 0

[DATA.dict.h]
type = Energy
from = 1127.11016043
to = 1210.58395722
line = 1

[DATA.dict.cc]
type = Energy
from = 3213.9954023
to = 3258.85057471
line = 2
```

I'm trying to use this code but it's not working for me as well.

```
 config._sections = collections.OrderedDict(sorted(config._sections.items(), key=lambda x: getattr(x, 'from') ))
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

`ConfigParser` uses `OrderedDict` internally, so you need to repopulate the parser in the order you need like so:

```py
from configparser import ConfigParser
from io import StringIO

ini_file = StringIO('''
[x]
hello = 123

[a]
from = 5.0

[b]
from = 3.0
''')

parser = ConfigParser()
parser.read_file(ini_file)


parser2 = ConfigParser()
sortable_sections = [s for s in parser if 'from' in parser[s]]
other_sections = [s for s in parser if 'from' not in parser[s]]

for s in other_sections:
    parser2[s] = parser[s]

for s in sorted(sortable_sections, key=lambda s: parser[s].getfloat('from')):
    parser2[s] = parser[s]

f = StringIO()
parser2.write(f)
f.seek(0)
print(f.read())
```

output:

```
[x]
hello = 123

[b]
from = 3.0

[a]
from = 5.0
```

Comment: Thanks! How would I read in my INI file with this? Right now I have: 
    configFilePath = datafile.ini
    parser.read(configFilePath)

Comment: it's just outputting a blank file for me.